# Putting a wordpress shortcode inbetween another wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Essentially I want to use a short code at some predetermined point in another short code.  My original Shortcode is grabbing a big chunk of text and I want to stick the next shortcode in at some point for a pull quote.

The only way I can think of is to use javascript to parse the original shortcode on page load for a certain character and insert the shortcode after that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Codex on nesting shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes):

> The shortcode parser correctly deals with nested shortcode macros, provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling `do_shortcode()`:

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-b]
      [tag-c]
   [/tag-b]
[/tag-a]
```

> However the parser will fail if a shortcode macro is used to enclose another macro of the same name:

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-a]
      [tag-c]
   [/tag-a]
[/tag-a]
```

Long story short: you can do this, as long as you follow the above rule.